# disable ETAG for JSON responses but enable ETAG for static assets

Tags: node.js, http, express, http-headers, etag

In our Express middleware, we have a call to:

```
 app.enable('etag');
```

the problem is that for JSON requests, the client will get a 304 status code for JSON requests that should always be re-evaluated/re-sent.

So my question is, using Express middleware, how can I enable etag for static assets, but disable it for JSON requests?

I'd probably have to inspect the headers for each request and enable/disable etags per request?

Answer (score 0):

So in production, it seems like this will work:

```
app.enable('etag');

app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "public")));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // we don't want to cache any JSON response
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store');
  next();
});

app.use(function(req,res){
   res.json({some:'this will never be cached'});
});
```

I think what this will accomplish is allow client caching of the static assets, but it will never cache any of the JSON responses in the client.